# Using index in css selector

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm using testcafe for automation and have dynamic css locator like this

```
this.infoQCLog = (index ,  name , date , subTitle , desc , index) => Selector('*[data-element-name = "content-checklog"]').nth(`${index}`).child('div').withText(`${name}`).nextSibling('div').withText(`${date}`).nextSibling('div').withText(`${subTitle}`).nextSibling('div').withText(`${desc}`)
```

but have issue that The "index" argument (string) is not of expected type (number). Have any solution that can resolved it ?

Comment: I'd start by **not** explicitly converting it to a string using a template literal.

Comment: Also, I'd avoid using `index` as the variable name for *two different arguments of the same function*!

Comment: yeah this info have a lot of line, i use in here to verify that data is in correct line

Comment: I have no idea what that comment refers to, it doesn't seem related to either of the comments I made.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```js
this.infoQCLog = (index, name, date, subTitle, desc) => {
    return Selector('*[data-element-name="content-checklog"]')
        .nth(Number(index))
        .child('div')
        .withText(`${name}`)
        .nextSibling('div')
        .withText(`${date}`)
        .nextSibling('div')
        .withText(`${subTitle}`)
        .nextSibling('div')
        .withText(`${desc}`);
};
```